# Retaining relative sizes of local maxima using MaxDetect[List]

Tags: list-manipulation, maximum

I would like to be able to find the position of the two greatest local maxima in a list.

For the example: `list={1,2,3,4,2,1,2,6,5,4,3,2,}`

I would like to return `{4,8}`

Initially I was using the `Ordering[list,-2]` to successfully do this, however, the above scenario shows that this fails quite easily (here 5>4).

I then tried using `Ordering[MaxDetect[list],-2]` which almost does the job; however, I have the problem that my list is long and has many (smaller) local maxima, which `MaxDetect` makes equal in value to the 2 larger local maxima, so `Ordering` fails to select the appropriate peaks.

Is there a way of retaining the relative sizes of the peaks after using `MaxDetect`, so that this method will work?

Thanks!

**Using the option `MaxDetect[list,value]` does not work, as  different runs change the value that these maxima have.

Comment: `{pos, value} = Transpose@FindPeaks[list]`. `pos` will return position desired {4,8}

Comment: Thank you! Using this and increasing sharpness has given me a great list of my data that I can easily manipulate!

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it explicitly, as follows,

```
findTwoMaxima[list_List] := Block[{l, p1, p2},
  l = list;
 (* find position of maximum:*)
  p1 = Flatten[Position[l, Max[l]]][[1]]; 
 (* Replace this entry by a very negative number:*)
  l[[p1]] = -Infinity;
 (* now find maximum again:*)
  p2 = Flatten[Position[l, Max[l]]][[1]];
  {p1, p2}
  ]
```

I always prefer writing your own code for doing simple stuff, so you don't have to rely on the fancy algorithm, which is a black box to you, that was used in `FindPeaks` or whatever other function you use.

Answer (score 3):

Following ubpdqn comment, this is the solution that worked for my problem:

`Peaks = Transpose@
   FindPeaks[Take[Delete[Abs[Fourier[CoM]], 1], RunTime/2], 0, 0];`

Find the position in Peaks of the two highest values (two greatest local peaks)

`MaxTwoPosition = Ordering[Peaks[[2]], -2];`

Find the corresponding position in my list of data:

`locationofbothpeaks = {Peaks[[1, MaxTwoPosition[[1]]]], 
  Peaks[[1, MaxTwoPosition[[2]]]]}`